# How to deactivate touch functions for the first few seconds after loading a new scene?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm building a simple SpriteKit game and I want to deactivate any touch functions for the first few seconds after a scene is loaded. I have an animated SKSpriteNode that needs to finish the animation before I want any touch functions to move the node. How do I approach setting this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use timers or the dispatch.  These do not correspond to your in game time.  If you exit your app or get a phone call, these will fire prematurely.

Instead, use an action on your scene:

```
let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration:2)
let run = SKAction.run{self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true}
self.run(SKAction.sequence[wait,run])
self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying! So dispatch and timers are in real time. If I were to get a phone call in the middle of the game, the time would still run rather than the method you provided above which stops the time until I get back to the game correct?

Comment: Right.  My method waits 2 in-game seconds.  (Providing you pause the scene properly [default behavior is properly]) Others wait 2 real world seconds

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to disable user interaction of super view and then run a timer with desired delay for the touch and enable the user interaction once the timer is invalidated.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense!